# history expansion by complete first word

Tags: zsh, expansion

Consider that I've successfully run these two commands in this order (but perhaps many commands ago):

```
~% ssh localhost echo
~% sshfs localhost:/ /media/copy-of-root
```

Now I would like to rerun the `ssh` command. My first instinct is to use `!ssh`, but this will match the `sshfs` command instead.

Is there a version of history expansion which will match entire first words instead of prefixes of commands? If not, is there some other robust way to choose the `ssh` command over the `sshfs` one?

Answer (score 1):

well, if you search for `ssh` (with a trailing space) it will find it. IMO the best alternative is to bind `up` and `down` to `up-line-or-search` and `down-line-or-search`.

```
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search # check the exact code for your UP key...
```

Then you would just use:

% ssh [UP]

which would search for `ssh` in your history. If that is not the history instance you want, just keep searching (i.e. hitting "UP").